# Is my Mips right for this forloop?

Tags: c, assembly, mips

Im trying to convert this small c code to mips but im curious if i did it correctly would someone be able to look it over and review? Trying to learn mips properly. Want to see if i got the hang of it. Using 4 registers here.

```
for (i=0; i<a; i++)
a += b;


li $t0,0
loop:
bge $t0,$s0,exit_loop
addi $t0,$t0,1
add $s0,$s0,$s1
j loop

exit_loop:
```

Comment: That loop is fairly nonsensical, did you mean `b += a` perhaps? Assuming `a` is `$s0` and `b` is `$s1`, your code is reasonable.

Comment: Assuming s0 holds a and s1 holds b that looks fine. Except I think you want b += a, otherwise your loop will never end.